# Bitcoin-cli -regtest getaccount, listaccounts, setaccount, method not found

Tags: bitcoin-cli, regtest

I just setup bitcoind (0.18.1) and put it in regtest mode, I am trying to work with accounts, but the account commands are not found...

setaccount

```
 jlroberts@mixerregtest:~$ bitcoin-cli -regtest setaccount 2NDCk4d7BYGztagf812gUdWqqPSMymdH4rS one
 error code: -32601
 error message:
 Method not found
```

getaccount

```
jlroberts@mixerregtest:~$ bitcoin-cli -regtest getaccount one
error code: -32601
error message:
Method not found
```

listaccounts

```
jlroberts@mixerregtest:~$ bitcoin-cli -regtest listaccounts
error code: -32601
error message:
Method not found
```

getblockchaininfo

```
{
  "chain": "regtest",
  "blocks": 303,
  "headers": 303,
  "bestblockhash": "77d7169d013574a1254ccf472389b40c3393f41498ddc6f84b8d078c740d3da3",
  "difficulty": 4.656542373906925e-10,
  "mediantime": 1568636861,
  "verificationprogress": 1,
  "initialblockdownload": false,
  "chainwork": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000260",
  "size_on_disk": 92175,
  "pruned": false,
  "softforks": [
    {
      "id": "bip34",
      "version": 2,
      "reject": {
        "status": false
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "bip66",
      "version": 3,
      "reject": {
        "status": false
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "bip65",
      "version": 4,
      "reject": {
        "status": false
      }
    }
  ],
  "bip9_softforks": {
    "csv": {
      "status": "locked_in",
      "startTime": 0,
      "timeout": 9223372036854775807,
      "since": 288
    },
    "segwit": {
      "status": "active",
      "startTime": -1,
      "timeout": 9223372036854775807,
      "since": 0
    }
  },
  "warnings": ""
}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What is your bitcoin core version? also, can you try `bitcoin-cli -regtest getblockchaininfo`?

Comment: using the latest, 0.18.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the listaccounts, getaccount and setaccount commands inside the Bitcoin core 18.1.

I think you have used the wrong commands with the bitcoin 18.1, perhaps the equivalents are:

- listaccounts -> [getwalletinfo](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.18.0/rpc/wallet/getaddressinfo/)
- setaccount -> [importaddress](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.18.0/rpc/wallet/importaddress/)

But before you use this command look the official documentation [rpc framework](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/)

Comment: ah I was using the documentation from https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

Answer (score 2):

`accounts` method was deprecated in v0.17 and was removed since v0.18. `accounts` was replaced by `label` and it provides more flexibility as compared to before such as setting label on any address, not just receiving address. It also irons out [issues raised in the past](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/3816). If you are used to using accounts to mimic separate wallets, you now have an option to use separate wallets in separate wallet files in Bitcoin Core.

So according to the commands you are looking, you will replace them by:

1. `getaccount` with `getaddressinfo`
2. `listaccounts` with `listlabels`
3. `setaccount` with `setlabel`

You can see the full documentation of accounts vs labels in the [v0.17 release docs](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/release-notes/release-notes-0.17.0.md#label-and-account-apis-for-wallet).